# Play a selected song in MediaLibrary WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Here is my problem : I have a LongListSelector which list songs from MediaLibrary and a SelectionChanged event. When the user taps on a song from the LongListSelector, it plays the song once, but then then it stops. But I'd like to play next song from the MediaLibrary once the selected song is finished

Here is my LongListSelector :

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsSongs" SelectionChanged="llsSongs_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,-30,0,0">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" FontSize="15" Opacity="0.75" Foreground="Black"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

and the SelectionChanged method

```
    private void llsSongs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Song _selectedSong = llsSongs.SelectedItem as Song;
        MediaPlayer.Play(_selectedSong);           
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged windows phone 7 and 8? Are you really targeting WP7?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at those articles

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phon

**EDIT:**

Based on your usage of the `MediaLibrary` and `MediaPlayer` XNA.Framework.Media namespace classes, you could take advantage of MediaPlayer's [MediaStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.mediastatechanged.aspx) event.

```
private void MediaPlayerOnMediaStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Stopped)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(nextSong);
    }
}
```

Since your collection holds the `Song`'s returned from MediaLibrary.Songs, SongCollection the nextSong will be the next index in your data bound collection.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The original question, contained nothing but a description on how to simulate a playlist on the platform, no code, what's been tried so far or whatsoever. I couldn't give any specific answer in such a generic question, although I admit a comment would be more suited.

Comment: I can't find an answer in either of those links. This answer is very low quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for